# Should I be suspicious of a conference that invites me, a recently admitted graduate student, to be an invited speaker?

Tags: conference, presentation, disreputable-publishers

I'm a recently-admitted student to graduate program, albeit possessing a considerable roster of research papers in known conferences and journals.

I'd just, recently, received an email from the chairman of [this conference](http://2conf.org/robotics/) to deliver a technical presentation, as an invited speaker in the target field.

Typically, invited speakers are the well-known heroes in their field. I am, noticeably, ambitious enough to taste such experience, but this offer's made me suspicious about the credibility of the conference, to the bone.

**Should I accept the offer?!**

Comment: It's a junk conference (if not a fake altogether). They are after your money and nothing else; speaking at this event will be of zero benefit to your career.

Comment: @ff524: You might be right. I did just consider some chances for its credibility, as some of the mentioned fellows in `committee` section are famous researchers. However, putting some fake names and pictures would not be too tough for such kinda junk administrators!

Comment: The chair of this "conference" series is also the chair of a [whole string](http://viewdns.info/reversewhois/?q=zhmwang%40gmail.com) of conferences and conference series of questionable quality, where virtually *all* the attendees are invited speakers (who pay $675 to attend). Save your time and your money for better opportunities.

Comment: (I edited the title of your post because it asked something completely different from the body. I hope this version is a better representation of what you're trying to ask.)

Comment: Go to the conference and pay in cash with fake money, do your presentation and then go to the beach.

Comment: @user4050: You just sound like a real engineer :)... Thanks

Comment: As a graduate student you should be wary of any offer to be invited speaker by someone you don't know well. You should also be seeking advice from your supervisor regarding this.

Comment: @Roboticist, DO NOT compound their fraud with your own fraud. This may be obvious to you, but counterfeiting is a serious crime in almost every country. For those who come late to this thread, user4050's comment was sarcastic and intended as humor.

Comment: @BillBarth: I'd just realized the case, noticeably... As the others would, considerably...

Comment: @BillBarth your efforts to protect random anonymous strangers on the internet from accidentally committing fraud due to blindly following the advice of other random anonymous strangers without realizing that said advice was made humorously, are very admirable and noble of course, but also, shall we say... amusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems it is a junk conference, which will not bring you anything, but waits for your money!

Don't go, it is a waste of time, you will get nothing good from it, since no one really involved at a high level in your field will come.

It is not unusual for those kind of conferences to invite "anyone" as an invited speaker.